# Flutter - how to run alarm app in background

Tags: android, ios, flutter, react-native, dart

I am want to build a alarm app in flutter with features
such as
:- stop alarm only by clicking button or only stop on event,
so how will i trigger the application on alarm to check the event?

Comment: Try to use this , let me know if it works https://tonydavidx.github.io/how-to-run-background-tasks-in-flutter/